# Java Recursion Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

Write a method with one positive int parameter called n. The method will write 2^n-1 integers (where ^ is the exponentiation operation). Here are the patterns of output for various values of n:

```
n=1: Output is: 1 
n=2: Output is: 1 2 1 
n=3: Output is: 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 
n=4: Output is: 1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1
```

And so on. Note that the output for n always consists of the output for n-1, followed by n itself, followed by a second copy of the output for n-1. Please help if you understand the question.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.  Best of all, each tutorial will teach you a collection of related techniques, rather than merely solving the immediate problem.

Comment: When asking about homework (1) **Be aware of your school policy**: asking here for help may constitute cheating. (2) Specify that the question is homework. (3) **Make a good faith attempt** to solve the problem yourself first (include your code in your question). (4) **Ask about a specific problem** with your existing implementation; see [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) is guidance on asking homework questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
//here is a solution that returns the result as a string
// this makes sense because the pattern on both sides of n are the patterns of  n-1 
public static String recursion(int n)
{ 
    if(n == 1)
    {
        return "1";
    }
    else
    {
        return recursion(n-1) + " " + n + " " + recursion(n-1);
    }
}
```